# Laravel eloquent creating a WHERE condition if and only if the table column has a specific value

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure if this is possible with Laravel eloquent, but I want to create an eloquent where the `where` condition would be based on the value of the current table column.

Something like this for illustration purposes:

```
...
if (column_a == 'paid')
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('status', '!=', 'failed');
    $q->where('status', '!=', 'cancelled');
})

else 
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('status', '!=', 'authorized');
})
...
->get();
```

`column_a` is part of the table column that I want to use. I could create 2 separate eloquent with their corresponding conditions and then merge them later but I dont want to go down that route if possible.

I thought of using `->when()` but based on what I understood, '->when()' is used for variable. Sorry if this is something basic but I dont really know how to proceed with this.

PS:

I also tried

```
->where('column_a', '=', 'paid', function($q) {
    $q->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('status', '!=', 'failed');
        $q->where('status', '!=', 'cancelled');
    });
})
->where('column_a', '!=', 'notpaid', function($q) {
    $q->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('status', '!=', 'authorized');
    });
})
```

But I am getting `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this :

```
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('column_a', '=', 'paid')
      ->where('status', '!=', 'failed')
      ->where('status', '!=', 'cancelled');
})
->orWhere(function($q) {
    $q->where('column_a', '!=', 'notpaid')
       ->where('status', '!=', 'authorized');
})
```

Comment: Oh. This makes much more sense that what I have tried to do. Thanks. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. This worked as I wanted. I don't know why I did not think of grouping my where clause like this. I was just over complicating my code yesterday.